# java KafkaConsumer never get results

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to kafka, I have the following sample code :

```
KafkaConsumer<String,String> kc = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
while(true) {
    List<String> topicNames = Arrays.asList(topics.split(","));
    if (!kc.assignment().isEmpty()) {
        kc.unsubscribe();
    }
    kc.subscribe(topicNames);
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> recv = kc.poll(1000L);
    if (!recv.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("NOT EMPTY");
    }
}
```

The recv is always empty but if I try to increment the pool timeout the records are returned, also if I cut off the unsubscribe part.

I've taken this piece of code from an integration proprietary software and I cannot modify it.

So my question is: Is this only a timing problem or there is more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot that happens when a consumer (re)subscribes to a topic.

Very roughly and as far as I remember the consumer will:

- request cluster information
- request consumer group metadata
- make a JOIN_GROUP request
- be assigned certain partitions

The underlying mechanisms are even more complicated if there are more consumers within the same group. That's because the partitions should be reassigned between all the consumers within the group.

That is why:

- 1000 millis might not be enough for all this and you didn't poll anything in time
- you polled something when you increased the timeout because Kafka managed to perform all of these bootstrapping operations
- you polled something when you removed the unsubscription to the topics because most likely your consumer was already subscribed

So there is a timing issue. And I think that there is something more - un/subscribing to a topic within an infinite loop makes no sense to me (see the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to your topics only once at the beginning. Like this:

```
 final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));

 while (true) {
     final ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
         System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
 }
```

Comment: I cannot modify the code, i find it decompiling some classes. I was wondering why if i increment the poll timeout it works fine